# How to display dates with same month as a single link?

Tags: php, mysql

I have an archive section for my blog. Every time there is a post, I want it to automatically display month name and year as a list, so later on I can click to view posts from that month and year.

I only know how to display using mysql_fetch_assoc, but this is going to keep repeating every row over and over, so I tried GROUP BY, but it does not help either.

```
<div class="sidebox widget">
    <h4>Por Datas</h4>

<?php 

$query = "SELECT * FROM posts GROUP BY post_date";
$select_all_post_by_dates = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_all_post_by_dates)) {

$post_id = $row['post_id'];
$post_date = $row['post_date'];
$post_date_month_year = date_create($post_date)
?>

<ul class="circled">
<li>
<a href="#"><?php echo date_format($post_date_month_year, "F Y")  ?>
</a>
</li>
</ul><!-- /.circled -->

<?php } ?>
<a href="#" class="txt-btn">All archives</a>
</div><!-- /.widget -->
```

The results are the months repeating one below the other, for example:

April 2019
April 2019
April 2019

In case I have one more post in May

April 2019
April 2019
April 2019
May 2019

And I needed:

April 2019
May 2019

Comment: use SELECT distinct post_date FROM posts

Answer (score 0):

Grouping by year and month in rows

```
SELECT
  Year(`post_date`),
  Month(`post_date`),
  Day(`post_date`),
  Count(*) As Total_Rows
FROM posts 
GROUP BY Year(`post_date`), Month(`post_date`), DAY(`post_date`)
```

Comment: My main problem is to display using php, would it be a lot to ask to complement with php part?